# out parameter not supported in pandas implementation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm doing a Datacamp course where they ask me to simultaneously use `.groupby()` and `.agg()` and the functions from the numpy package `np.min`, `np.max`, `np.mean`, `np.median`. When I try running the script, it throws an error on line 5.

Also, why isn't it necessary to put a parenthesis inside the agg method?

```
# Import numpy with the alias np
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# The DataFrame "sales" is already implemented

# For each store type, aggregate weekly_sales: get min, max, mean, and median
sales_stats = sales.groupby("type")["weekly_sales"].agg(np.min,np.max,np.mean,np.median)

# Print sales_stats
print(sales_stats)

# For each store type, aggregate unemployment and fuel_price_usd_per_l: get min, max, mean, and median
unemp_fuel_stats = sales.groupby("type")["unemployment","fuel_price_usd_per_l"].agg(np.min,np.max,np.mean,np.median)

# Print unemp_fuel_stats
print(unemp_fuel_stats)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `sales`

Comment: What is the full error message? Where is the error? Line 5 is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, this is the line in question:

```
sales.groupby("type")["weekly_sales"].agg(np.min,np.max,np.mean,np.median)
```

Here's what probably happened. The `agg` method can receive not one but several positional arguments, where the first one is the function(s) to use for aggregating the data, and the following positional arguments are passed to those function(s). Note `*args` in the signature of `.agg`:

```
.agg(func=None, *args, engine=None, engine_kwargs=None, **kwargs)
```

So `add` will run `np.min` with three additional positional argument, like this:

```
np.min(group, axis=np.max, out=np.mean, keepdims=np.median)
```

As I can understand, `pandas` checks if it can run the function with passed parameters, and it turns out that the parameter `out=` of `numpy.min` isn't supported. That's why you've got

```
ValueError: the 'out' parameter is not supported in the pandas implementation of ...`
```

(not sure, but I guess there should be `min` at the end of the above error in your case)

Let's model the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': (t:=[*'abc']*5),
    'weekly_sales':[*range(len(t))]    
})

my_min = lambda x, *args: print(f'{args=}') or np.min(x)

sales.groupby('type')['weekly_sales'].agg(my_min, np.max, np.mean, np.median)
```

I replaced `np.min` with my function to see, if the very first function do obtain all other positional arguments passed to `.agg`. In the output you should see something like this:

[image: output of the test function]

To make `.agg` work correctly, we need to pass all functions as a list-like object (put them in some parenthesis), i.e. pass all of them as one iterable object. Sort of:

[image: output of correct agg]

See also:

- [about aggregation in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html?highlight=agg#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg)
- [about numpy.min](https://numpy.org/doc/stable//reference/generated/numpy.min.html)